# Android HorizontalScrollView get width

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement a horizontal ListView using a HorizontalScrollView and adding 'items' to it within the code. Adding the items works fine. Now I want each item to be 1/7 of the ScrollView's width so I can display exactly 7 items without scrolling. I cannot figure out a way to get the width of the HorizontalScrollView.

My XML looks like this:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/information_popup_dialog_listScrollView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="7" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/information_popup_dialog_listParent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>   
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

I add an item like this:

```
LinearLayout listContainer = (LinearLayout) view
            .findViewById(R.id.information_popup_dialog_listParent);
LinearLayout listItem = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.information_popup_dialog_list_item, listContainer,
                false);
listItem.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                width, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
listContainer.addView(listItem);
```

When I use measure() to get the width of the ScrollView I get the total width, not the visible width. So it keeps growing with every item I add.

```
HorizontalScrollView scrollView = (HorizontalScrollView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.information_popup_dialog_listScrollView);
scrollView.measure(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
System.out.println("Width: " + scrollView.getMeasuredWidth());
```

I tried different ways using .getLayoutParams().width / getWidth(), both return 0.
Is there anyway to do this?
I'm doing all of this in the onCreateView() method of a DialogFragment.

Answer (score 0):

You can get device's screen width, and then divide it by 7. Now, set this number you get after dividing screen width, as the width of your each view in HorizontalScrollView. This way you can have exactly 7 items visible on your screen.

I haven't tried this, but it should work and it is pretty easy to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use `view.getWidth()` in `onViewCreated()`. `LayoutParameters.width` will return the value you put in the XML.

If it's still not working , then you'll need to `getWidth` inside the `view.post()` method. This makes sure the view has been laid out.